# X-box 360 never stops blinking - LTS 16.04.3

Tags: lts, xbox-360

Im using wired xbox controller and using LTS 16.04-3. Controller does not work and continues blinking after booting ubuntu, You physically need to unplug and replug the controller so that it would work. using steamos-xpad and xboxdrv does not solve this problem since it still needs to be unplugged and replug.

Similar issue happens when using non-lts releases. Wasnt' this issue fixed with steam a long time ago?